# What does the Funcion: indices_list = np.where(np.any(crop_img != [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)) do?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

```
crop_img = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
cv2.imshow("crop_img", crop_img)
```

[image]

```
indices_list = np.where(np.any(crop_img != [0, 0, 0], axis=-1))
print("indices_list", indices_list)
```

[image]

```
roi_pixel_img = crop_img[indices_list]
print("roi_pixel_img" , roi_pixel_img)
print("roi_pixel_img shape, roi_pixel_img.shape)
```

[image]
[image]

my questions are simple.

1. What do we do to generate the indices list?
2. what exactly do we get from the indices list in terms of crop_img?
3. The latter, I don't understand the connection between crop_img and indices_list.

Comment: In terms of `crop_img`, `indices_list` stores the coordinates of the image where there are non 0 value pixels in the image array

Comment: why do i get two arrays ? for x and y Position ?

Comment: Yes, one array each for the X and Y coordinate

Comment: okay, so the first coordinate is 186, 346

Comment: Yes. Also you can iterate through both the coordinate arrays simultaneously using `zip`